# How do I run Age of Empires three on ubuntu?

Tags: age-of-empires-iii

I've been trying to play this game for awhile now but when it opens it asks for the l3codecx.ax why is this and how do i get around it?

Answer (score 2):

Installing Age Of Empires III requires 4 DLLs:

```
mfc42.dll
quartz.dll
d3dx9_36.dll
l3codecx.ax
```

Of these, `l3codecx.ax` is by far the hardest to obtain, as it's not independently available on the internet.  The [WineHQ page for AoE3](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3795) has an entire section devoted to obtaining this file (most of this is paraphrased from there, and my own experience installing the game).

**Acquiring the l3codecx.ax file**

> There are a few ways you are able to get this file. Choose one of the
>   following:
>
> - Copy the file from an existing Windows install `(C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32)`
> - Copy it from a Windows XP install cd by issuing the following command
>     `"wine d:/i386/expand.exe d:/i386/l3codecx.ax_ h:/.wine/l3codecx.ax"`
>     assuming wine has d:/ mapped to a cd drive with a Windows XP install
>     cd and h:/ is mapped to your home directory.
> - Install a codec pack with the file:
>
>   - Download [this](http://www.digital-digest.com/software/download.php?sid=577&ssid=0&did=1) file.
>   - Run BCM1043.exe with wine, it will ask for installing Gecko HTML engine too, install it. After installing, it will create a folder
>       called `~/.wine/drive_c/Program Files/BCM/`. Copy the file l3codecx.ax
>       under `'Codecs/DIRECTS/Fraunhofer/'` to
>       `~/.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/`.

Once it is obtained:

> Open a terminal and cd to the `C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32` directory and type `"wine regsvr32 l3codecx.ax"` (Without quotes)
>
> Install Age of Empires III as usual.

I strongly suggest you read [the WineHQ page on Age of Empires III](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=3795) in full, as it contains countless little tweaks to get around potentially game-breaking problems.

---

Personally, I got it running with [PlayOnLinux](http://www.playonlinux.com/en/), which is a collection of scripts for running various games under Wine that streamlines the process to nearly as easy as a conventional installer.